# Big Data Process and Analysis in R

Tags: r, bigdata

I know this is not a new concept by any stretch in R, and I have browsed the High Performance and Parallel Computing Task View.  With that said, I am asking this question from a point of ignorance as I have no formal training in Computer Science and am entirely self taught.

Recently I collected data from the Twitter Streaming API and currently the raw JSON sits in a 10 GB text file.  I know there have been great strides in adapting R to handle big data, so how would you go about this problem?  Here are just a handful of the tasks that I am looking to do:

1. Read and process the data into a data frame
2. Basic descriptive analysis, including text mining (frequent terms, etc.)
3. Plotting

Is it possible to use R entirely for this, or will I have to write some Python to parse the data and throw it into a database in order to take random samples small enough to fit into R.

Simply, any tips or pointers that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Again, I won't take offense if you describe solutions at a 3rd grade level either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If thinking of creative and efficient code becomes too burdensome, you could try throwing a bigger computer at the data. For ~$2 / hour, you can rent a linux instance from Amazon with 68 gigs of RAM. Thanks to the good folks at Bioconductor, you can use one of their prefigured AMI's with a reasonably up to date version of R already installed, and even set up the RStudio web interface with ease. Details [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I was unaware of the Bioconductor setup, but have heard of similar setups.  One thing I struggle with is how the data that resides on my computer is processed "faster" with external computers that I connect to over the web.  In addition, would this allow me to load and process all 10gb of data using R on my machine?

Comment: when I've worked with EC2, I've moved my data "to the cloud" via scp or similar protocols. Then the data and code reside in the same spot. So my workflow looks like this: 1. fire up EC2, 2. move data and code to EC2, 3. run simulation, 4. retrieve all the above and close EC2 instance. I know you can also take advantage of Amazon's S3 service to host / store your data and make that talk to EC2, though I haven't had a need *yet* to go that route.

Comment: A better solution is to download the json file, convert it to a data.frame, insert it into a MySQL database. This way, you avoid getting the 10GB file to be created and you can then query the DB.

Comment: I've got several gzipped data sets in S3 that are tens to hundreds of GB each.  My plan is to load the data into Spark in EC2, use SparkR from R (also on EC2) to call Spark SQL that does some of the manipulations and aggregations, and then bring in chunks small enough that I can do the rest with data.table in R.  Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to operate on the entire 10GB file at once, then I second @Chase's point about getting a larger, possibly cloud-based computer.

(The Twitter streaming API returns a pretty rich object: a single 140-character tweet could weigh a couple kb of data.  You might reduce memory overhead if you preprocess the data outside of R to extract only the content you need, such as author name and tweet text.)

On the other hand, if your analysis is amenable to segmenting the data -- for example, you want to first group the tweets by author, date/time, etc -- you could consider using Hadoop to drive R.

Granted, Hadoop will incur some overhead (both cluster setup and learning about the underlying MapReduce model); but if you plan to do a lot of big-data work, you probably want Hadoop in your toolbox anyway.

A couple of pointers:

- an example in chapter 7 of [Parallel R](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021421.do) shows how to setup R and Hadoop for large-scale tweet analysis.  The example uses the RHIPE package, but the concepts apply to any Hadoop/MapReduce work.
- you can also get a Hadoop cluster via AWS/EC2.  Check out 
  Elastic MapReduce
  for an on-demand cluster, or use 
  [Whirr](http://whirr.apache.org/)
  if you need more control over your Hadoop deployment.

Comment: Good answer.  Just a suggestion: it's good to disclose if you're the author of a work that you cite.  :)

Comment: @qethanm  Do you have any suggestions on what would be a good free alternative to Hadoop that is HIPPA compliant?  My data is in the 10^13 currently but depending on the  research question our final analysis could involve only a fraction of the original data.

Answer (score 5):

There's a brand-new package called `colbycol` that lets you read in only the variables you want from enormous text files:

http://colbycol.r-forge.r-project.org/

> read.table function remains the main data import function in R. This
>   function is memory inefficient and, according to some estimates, it
>   requires three times as much memory as the size of a dataset in order
>   to read it into R.
>
> The reason for such inefficiency is that R stores data.frames in
>   memory as columns (a data.frame is no more than a list of equal length
>   vectors) whereas text files consist of rows of records. Therefore, R's
>   read.table needs to read whole lines, process them individually
>   breaking into tokens and transposing these tokens into column oriented
>   data structures.
>
> ColByCol approach is memory efficient. Using Java code, tt reads the
>   input text file and outputs it into several text files, each holding
>   an individual column of the original dataset. Then, these files are
>   read individually into R thus avoiding R's memory bottleneck.
>
> The approach works best for big files divided into many columns,
>   specially when these columns can be transformed into memory efficient
>   types and data structures: R representation of numbers (in some
>   cases), and character vectors with repeated levels via factors occupy
>   much less space than their character representation.
>
> Package ColByCol has been successfully used to read multi-GB datasets
>   on a 2GB laptop.

Answer (score 2):

10GB of JSON is rather inefficient for storage and analytical purposes.  You can use `RJSONIO` to read it in efficiently.  Then, I'd create a memory mapped file.  You can use `bigmemory` (my favorite) to create different types of matrices (character, numeric, etc.), or store everything in one location, e.g. using HDF5 or SQL-esque versions (e.g. see RSQlite).

What will be more interesting is the number of rows of data and the number of columns.

As for other infrastructure, e.g. EC2, that's useful, but preparing a 10GB memory mapped file doesn't really require much infrastructure.  I suspect you're working with just a few 10s of millions of rows and a few columns (beyond the actual text of the Tweet).  This is easily handled on a laptop with efficient use of memory mapped files.  Doing complex statistics will require either more hardware, cleverer use of familiar packages, and/or experimenting with some unfamiliar packages.  I'd recommend following up with a more specific question when you reach that stage.  The first stage of such work is simply data normalization, storage and retrieval.  My answer for that is simple: memory mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

To read chunks of the JSON file in, you can use the scan() function. Take a look at the skip and nlines arguments. I'm not sure how much performance you'll get versus using a database.